# vagrant ssh - asks for password after adding synced_folder

Tags: ssh, nfs, rsync, vagrant

I can vagrant ssh into my box fine

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.16.0-30-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
Last login: Mon Apr 13 13:05:26 2015 from 10.0.2.2
vagrant@web01:~$
```

in my provisioning script, I have added the following and subsequently tried with nfs and rsync also.

```
web.vm.synced_folder ".", "/home/vagrant"
```

When I do this, when I `vagrant reload`, I am asked for a password.

```
vagrant@127.0.0.1's password:
```

As soon as I comment out the synced folder and vagrant reload again, I get the following message. I ctrl+c which hangs

```
==> web: Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
Text will be echoed in the clear. Please install the HighLine or Termios libraries to suppress echoed text.
vagrant@127.0.0.1's password:^C==> web: Waiting for cleanup before exiting...
```

I can't even vagrant reload --provision as I am asked for a password.

So I have to `vagrant destroy` and `vagrant up` again removing the synced_folder line in order to ssh into the vagrant box.

I don't know if this makes any difference, but my host machine is OSX

Comment: I'm also seeing the same thing sometimes with Vagrant VMs that use shared folders (also using OSX as the host). I think it's kind of a "phantom" password request. If you just hit Enter, it will prompt a couple times but then boot normally. (At least in my cases.)

Comment: also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23599297/changing-vagrantfile-causes-vagrant-ssh-to-prompt-for-a-password